# Bug/issue tracker for small extent team

Tags: java, git, issue-tracker, subversion

What issue/bug tracker would you recommend for a small extent company? Approx. (5-7 people).

My preference is lightweight, with compatibility of all operation systems, practical and appealing user interface, tasks assignment for different people, agile and scrum support, **SVN** and **Git** support, **commits** representation, very good support of **Java**, Spring and Hibernate, multi-project tracking possibility. Those should be main capabilities.

JIRA is too extensive. I am thinking about YouTrack or Easy-Redmine. What are your considerations?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! I've just added the [issue-tracker](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/issue-tracker) tag to your question, please check [its answered questions](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=[issue-tracker]+answers%3A1), there are already some good recommendations. Some more are [tagged project-management](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=[project-management]+answers%3A1).

Comment: By "JIRA is too extensive", do you mean that it's too complex for you?  Or do you mean *expensive*?  If the former: I use it at home by myself for my own software development, and I don't find it intrusive.  If the latter, it's $US 10 per month for up to 10 users.

Comment: If you *do* mean expensive, could you please state a budget which you would find acceptable, or use the [tag:gratis] tag?

Comment: In embedded software, [Bugzilla](https://www.bugzilla.org/) is still the standard when looking for a free solution; else Jira

Answer (score 1):

We used [Github](https://github.com/) for a while and then [Gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/). Github is more popular and intuitive but more expensive for private projects. Gitlab is more cumbersome and slow but free for all projects and has more out-of-the-box features (but size limit on each project). They both are based around Git but I don't think they support SVN though. You could check that [article if you really need legacy SVN compatibility](http://www.netinstructions.com/git-and-svn-together/).

Answer (score 1):

Full disclosure: I am the founder & CEO of [Comb](https://www.withcomb.com)

[Comb](https://www.withcomb.com) was built for teams that value efficiency. The primary focus is on a prioritized task list, and getting through that list. Comb assigns work to team members (when they request work) based on the priority list, along with a set of user-defined rules that allow work to flow through the team in a way that makes sense for your team.

I think that Comb meets your needs for lightweight, compatibility (web-based with good browser support), appealing user interface (although that's subjective!), and multi-project tracking. Comb doesn't enforce a methodology of working (Scrum, Kanban, etc.), but does give you custom buttons to automate your workflow.

Integration-wise, we again try to remain flexible, by allowing Comb to call external services, and receive data via webhooks. This allows you to set up integrations to most systems, and we are in the process of adding in some pre-built integrations.

Comment: This looks good, but I don't see a price list

Comment: @Mawg price list added

Comment: At https://www.withcomb.com/pricing/ It is free in Beta, then $20/month for unlimited projects (he wrote, doing @flipchart's marketing for him :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are a good few options out there, looking over your requirements here are a couple of cheaper / free options may be most suitable.

- [GitHub](https://github.com) - If you are already using this for code versioning, then it may be worth taking a look at the issue tracking functionality. Its pretty basic, but it does tie in very well with the code side of things.
- [Trello](https://trello.com/) - A free tool which is lightweight, works well with agile teams and has various addons.
- [Teamwork Projects](https://www.teamwork.com/project-management-software) or [Redbooth](https://redbooth.com/) - If you want a little more functionality and are willing to pay a little, then these may be worth looking at.

I hope this helps, but if you want any more suggestions then I've recently been involved in putting this [defect management tool list](https://blog.testlodge.com/defect-management-tools-list/) together of all the best options which are currently available should any of the above not be suitable.